# Ability to cast for overload cost or just cast

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Dreadhorde Arcanist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDreadhorde%20Arcanist%5d) allows you to "cast target instant or sorcery card with converted mana cost equal to or less than dreadhorde arcanists power from your graveyard without paying its mana cost" but for cards with overload costs that state in it's own separate ruling that we "may" cast it for its overload cost, can I use dreadhorde archanist to reach and have the ability to cast a card like "weapon surge", then choose to pay its overload cost for its overload effect?

Answer (score 6):

**No, you cannot pay the overload cost for spells cast that way**.

Dreadhorde Arcanist allows you to cast a spell with an alternate cost of "without paying its mana cost", as described in rule 118.9:

> Some spells have alternative costs. An alternative cost is a cost listed in a spell's text, or applied to it from another effect, that its controller may pay rather than paying the spell's mana cost. Alternative costs are usually phrased, "You may [action] rather than pay [this object's] mana cost," or **"You may cast [this object] without paying its mana cost."** Note that some alternative costs are listed in keywords; see rule 702.

The Overload ability also defines an alternate cost in rule 702.95a:

> Overload is a keyword that represents two static abilities that function while the spell with overload is on the stack. Overload [cost] means **"You may choose to pay [cost] rather than pay this spell's mana cost"** and "If you chose to pay this spell's overload cost, change its text by replacing all instances of the word 'target' with the word 'each.'" **Using the overload ability follows the rules for paying alternative costs** in rules 601.2b and 601.2f-h.

Then rule 118.9a says this:

> Only one alternative cost can be applied to any one spell as it's being cast. The controller of the spell announces their intentions to pay that cost as described in rule 601.2b.

Since Dreadhorde Arcanist's effect specifically allows you to cast the spell with its alternate cost, you cannot choose to pay the overload cost.

Comment: "Since Dreadhorde Arcanist's effect specifically allows you to cast the spell with ITS alternate cost, you cannot choose to pay the overload cost". Very Good Murgatroid, I just edit you this orthographic error (I tried to edit your answer, but it takes at least 6 characters to edit it), then your edited answer is really the truth. As usual ... you're right,and  I'm sorry. But I'm sure I made some correct observations in my answer, which made you change your answer.

Answer (score -6):

I believe that a player has the right to choose an instant or sorcery card with  overload, and to play it through his overloaded ability too.
This is also because *Gatherer's rulings* on *Weapon Surge* card explicity say that (15/4/2013):

> - "Casting a spell with overload doesn’t change that spell’s mana cost. You just pay the overload cost instead".

The fact that the overload cost is reduced to zero means nothing.
The Gatherer's rulings that say:

> "If you are instructed to cast a spell with overload "without paying its mana cost", you can't choose to pay its overload cost instead"

it only means that,if the player,for some strange reason,want to pay the mana, would not however: he cannot choose to pay the mana indicated by the overload ability even if he wanted to.
But it doesn't mean that the overload ability can't be played for this reason.
Thus, since Dreadhorde Arcanist has a power equal to 1, and Weapon Surge converted mana cost is 1 too, then everything is ok, and **it would seem** that the answer to this question could be:- "Yes" .

(*In fact, my first answer to this question was just that. The following is not all flour of my bag, but is rather due to the inspiration followed by the vision of the excellent response of Murgatroid99, to which I refer*).

But it is now important to say that:

> Only one alternative cost can be applied to any one spell as it's being cast. The controller of the spell announces their intentions to pay that cost as described in rule 601.2b.

Thus, it is for this reason that the answer to this question cannot be positive.
Since you are already forced to pay an alternative cost (that is "without paying its mana cost"), you cannot choose to pay for a different one.
In other words,you cannot pay the overload cost,since it is a kind of alternative cost.

Comment: This is not correct. I've edited my own answer with a more complete explanation of how this works.

Comment: I don't think I want to reconsider my answer, although I must admit that, since overload is an "alternative cost", the operation that I describe with my answer is really at the limit of legitimacy. This is also because Dreadhorde Arcanist  offers no instructions regarding how to behave with any additional costs. And then, more often than not, we always end up answering such questions: - "No". but The Murgatroid's edited question is the correct one, I must admit...

Comment: However, I congratulate Austin Duesing, since in my opinion he has found a really good question, I thought it was some sort of regulatory vacuum before Murgatroid found the correct answer. I must say that this is why I preferred to answer: - "Yes", to your question, in contrast with what it usually happens. If someone finds an anomaly, not for this reason, one should immediately say "No" to his proposal. Then, Murgatroid found the key to the problem, and I think his answer is the best.

Comment: Your first sentence (“I believe that a player has the right to choose an instant or sorcery card with overload, and to play it through his overloaded ability too.”) and last sentence (“In other words,you cannot pay the overload cost,since it is a kind of alternative cost.”) provide contradictory advice. I suggest revising this answer if you want to keep it. It's not important to keep a journey of discovery about the answer: if you first answer “yes” and then realise the answer is “no”, we would prefer to see an answer that says just “no”, not one that says “yes, wait, actually no.”

Comment: Consider that e.g. Encyclopedias do not keep information they later discover to be incorrect, they remove it. Or they give the clear correct information, then may acknowledge commonly held incorrect beliefs.

Comment: There is no contradiction. The answer at the end clearly says that: -"Thus, it is for this reason that the answer to this question cannot be positive". My answer clearly clarifies all the steps that are intuitively done to get to the right answer. I leave them all.Murgatroid99 instead does not tell you that, before my answer, he too had been wrong, because he had said "No", but motivating everything incorrectly.

Comment: Murgatroid99 right answer is also due to the fact that I pointed out that :-"The fact that the overload cost is reduced to zero means nothing", when you put it in relation to the ruling that says:- "Casting a spell with overload doesn't change that spell's mana cost. You just pay the overload cost instead ". But of course I only highlighted this notation. I like to keep mistakes clearly visible, and think about how the applicant would do.Many, however, correct them because they fear the consequences of an incorrect answer, in terms of reputation ... It is easy to correct errors in this way!

Comment: Anyway I understand you, DoppelGreener: you criticized my answer because you didn't follow the times of this post in the way you should have; that is, following the way in which the various answers have alternated each other.But,next time, wait or ask to find out more, before criticizing, and rating down the answer... However, it's true, and I admitted it immediately and explicitly: Murgatroid's answer is really great,and I refer to this one for giving a right answer (Since mine, however, remains a correct answer: edited, but still a correct one).